Auto Run Failure
I have a macro set to auto run using the "This Workbook" option.  It used to work fine.  Then it stopped - except when I copy the workbook to a new name.  Then when I open the workbook for the first time and "enable content" the macro auto runs.  But on subsequent opening of that workbook the macro does not run.  Any suggestions on a fix?
I have not changed the code since it was working normally.  I did go from a dedicated version of Excel - loaded locally - to Office 365.  I'm wondering if there is something in security settings or Office 365 that is keeping the autorun feature from working "normally".

If you need help figuring out why your macro doesn't run, we'll need to see the macro.

"I did go from a dedicated version of Excel - loaded locally - to Office 365" If you mean you are using the online version, that will not run VBA.
